# Should C++ questions about dynamic allocation be tagged with heap-memory?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [heap-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap-memory) tagline says:

> The heap is process memory set aside for dynamic allocation.

Which seems vague enough to cover questions that have dynamic allocation in it, but the tag wiki gives a different story:

> A [heap memory
>   pool](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sag2/html/sag2/sag274.htm)
>   is an internal memory pool created at start-up that tasks use to
>   dynamically allocate memory as needed. This memory pool is used by
>   tasks that requires a lot of memory from the stack, such as tasks that
>   use wide columns.
>
> For example, in Sybase's [Adaptive Server
>   Enterprise](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/adaptiveserverenterprise),
>   if you make a wide column or row change, the temporary buffer this
>   task uses can be as large as 16K, which is too big to allocate from
>   the stack. Adaptive Server dynamically allocates and frees memory
>   during the task’s runtime.
>
> The heap memory pool dramatically reduces the predeclared stack size
>   for each task, while also improving the efficiency of memory usage in
>   the server. The heap memory the task uses is returned to the heap
>   memory pool when the task is finished.
>
> Microsoft [describes a
>   heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188270%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
>   for their SQL Server 2008 R2 as a table without a clustered index.
>   Heaps have one row in sys.partitions, with index_id = 0 for each
>   partition used by the heap. By default, a heap has a single partition.
>   When a heap has multiple partitions, each partition has a heap
>   structure that contains the data for that specific partition. For
>   example, if a heap has four partitions, there are four heap
>   structures; one in each partition.

The C++ standard has references to "dynamic allocation" and "dynamic storage duration", but AFAIK has no notion of the "heap" or "stack", which are operating system specifics. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711536/initializing-a-stdvector-from-a-count-and-an-element-value-with-copies/26711765#comment42015571_26711765)'s a conversation dealing with this misconception:

> pezy: the `temporary object` exist in the stack? or heap?
>
> remyabel: @pezy That's an operating system detail.
>
> pezy: @remyabel some guys say: use `new` would put in heap, otherwise
>   in stack? Is it right?
>
> MSalters: @pezy: The short answer is no, the long answer would start
>   with "perhaps..." but not fit in a comment. As remyabel points out,
>   the OS is really in charge and C++ just tells you how long the object
>   lives, not where. ( "heap" => "until delete", "stack" => "until
>   function returns", "global" => until program exits, "temporary" =>
>   until end of statement)

With that in mind, it doesn't seem appropriate to use [heap-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap-memory) if it's a platform-agnostic question. It looks like [dynamic-memory-allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-memory-allocation) is a much better tag as it actually references [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

> Dynamic memory allocation, usually in the context [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) or
>   [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), refers to the process of asking the operating system for a
>   variable sized block of memory.
>
> In those languages, allocation involves the use of a few different
>   techniques:
>
> - `malloc` (C), `operator new` (C++)
> - `free` (C), `operator delete` (C++)

Thoughts?

Comment: That wiki is horrendous.

Comment: @Mat Which one?

Comment: The [heap-memory] one, talks about two database implementations of "heap" (the SQL Server thing storage too, not memory...) that just aren't what people mean in general when talking about heap memory.

Comment: OT: I get really annoyed by the pedants who say that C/C++ doesn't specify anything about heap or stack allocation. Conceptually, the heap is whatever new/malloc use, the stack is where local variables live. Whether they directly correspond with some OS feature is irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmer While I agree that for all intents and purposes it's OK to talk about the heap and stack, my problem is people conflating the terminology and tagging questions with whatever seems vaguely relevant.

Comment: @Barmar: I get really annoyed when people conflate semantics and implementation-details. In this specific instance, did you know that compiler optimizers could place new'ed objects on the stack?

Comment: That's an implementation detail. Memory that can conceptually last after the function returns is semantically a heap.

Comment: The two terms are not so precise as you think.  Trying to draw a distinction between them isn't helpful.  In other contexts "heap" does have a precise technical meaning, but it doesn't mean anything like that here.  Heap is used here to connote utter unconcern with how the contents are organized -- there are garbage-collected heaps, first-fit heaps, buddy-system heaps, best-fit heaps, heaps with no reclamation at all, and I bet ten minutes digging could turn up a dozen more.  I even think I remember someone using a (real) heap (the data structure) to implement efficient first-fit.

Comment: (Yep. [Here it is](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb089.pdf), and its author makes the same point I just did: "Thus, ST[l], , . . , ST[2S - I] is a “heap” in the sense of [13], Sect. 5.2.31, though 
we shall avoid using the word heap as it has a different meaning in the context 
of dynamic storage allocation. ")

Comment: @jthill That sounds like an argument in favor of retagging. Newbies get caught up on "heap" and "stack" because they don't really understand what it means.

Comment: By that logic, all jargon should be thrown overboard, in every technical field -- and if that seems to be stretching it too far, I'll just say that if there's _any_ technical domain where dumbing down the language to avoid confusing newbies is out of place, it's ... C++ ... :-)

Comment: @jthill It's not dumbing down the language if the heap and stack are not a part of the language. Nobody has to care about it because C++ abstracts it away. But when somebody ignores modern C++ practice and opts to use manual memory management, more likely than not, they're going to encounter the "heap" and be utterly confused. The idea is to avoid this kind of confusion by not throwing loaded words around and say exactly what you mean. i.e., "I want to allocate something on the heap", versus "I want to use dynamic memory allocation".

Comment: @Barmar And I get really annoyed when people stubbornly refuse to accept that their choice of terminology — that they're hanging on to for no apparent reason whatsoever other than, I guess, to be obstinate in the face of more intelligent reasoning — is naively inaccurate and harmfully misleading. Your "conceptual" example is laughably incomplete.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828254/error-regarding-segmentation-fault-in-one-way-but-not-in-other-why) is an example of someone extrapolating "stack" to "allocate space statically" when they're talking about automatic storage duration.

Comment: @Barmar - _I get really annoyed by_ : Very correct IMO. That dialog up there is just plain **wrong.** Stroustrup himself talks in many places about the _free store_ as opposed to the _stack_. The concepts have **nothing to do with the OS** AFAIK, but with how C++ applications manage memory.

Comment: @Vector: [Stroustrup says many things](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18086575/560648). Just because one man says something.... gees, you know what? Just never mind.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I'd say he carries a bit more weight than just any old "one man". And he doesn't say it just once - he uses the term throughout his book. But just never mind. The intent is clear, regardless and IMO this whole thread is unecessary pendantics. Whether you tag it _free store_ or _heap memory_ or _dynamic memory allocation_ people will know what you mean.

Comment: @remyabel - that example simply proves that there are some people who don't know very much. I don't believe it's all relevant to your point.

Comment: @Vector: I guess you didn't click on my link. And this whole "people will know what you mean" myth is absurd. Daily I see people get this stuff wrong and write bugs in their code and come here with silly problems because other people have been teaching them misleading and confusing terms. It's so _pointless_ to do that. I cannot fathom why so many people are so dead set on doing it. Some people just want to watch the world burn, I guess. But, hey, being precise and diligent is "being pedantic" nowadays, so whatever.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - When I said _people will know what you mean_ I was talking about tags on this site, that's all. That's the subject of the thread. Most people will "get it" - like you said below _stick with C++_ . Obviously correct terminology is important when discussing and communicating program design.

Answer (score 7):

On the surface of it, yes: [dynamic-memory-allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-memory-allocation) is more "correct" than [heap-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heap-memory).

However, in fact, *neither* of those tags is of any use at all. You're not going to get someone filtering their front page to see "dynamic allocation" questions, or searching specifically for questions on dynamic allocation. Y'know, unless they *really* like dynamic allocation....

Stick with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and leave it at that.

Comment: Tags are also used as search terms, not just front page filters.  dynamic-allocation also exists.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I knew someone would say that. I'd argue that the same logic applies there.

Comment: Stroustrup prefers _free store_.

Comment: @Vector: Yep, dynamic allocation — _with a default allocator_ — results in objects being allocated on the free store.

Comment: _ dynamic allocation... results in objects being allocated on the free store_ - he doesn't us the term _dynamically allocated memory_ :) Enough time wasted on this nonsense. As far as tags go IMO it's not important.